# No alive nodes found in your cluster, Laravel, docker

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm experimenting with ElasticSearch using laravel. Here's my config thus far:-

**config/elasticquent.php**

```
return array(

 'config' => [
    'hosts'     => ['localhost:9200'],
    'retries'   => 1,
 ],

 'default_index' => 'contents',
);
```

**app/Content.php**

```
class Content extends Model
{
 use ElasticquentTrait;

 protected $fillable = ['title', 'text', 'image'];

 protected $mappingProperties = array(
    'title' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'text' => [
        'type' => 'text',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'image' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
 );
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 App\Content::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);
 App\Content::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);
 App\Content::addAllToIndex();

 return view('contents.index', [
    'contents' => App\Content::all(),
 ]);
});

Route::get('/search', function() {
 return App\Content::searchByQuery(['match' => ['title' => 'Adipisci']]);
});
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
 "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
}

// database/migrations/2020_12_12_105155_create_contents_table.php
public function up()
{
 Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('text');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->timestamps();
 });
}
```

My app is running on a docker container at: `http://localhost:3024`  My elasticsearch is also running on a docker container at:

```
docker run --rm -d -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:6.8.1
```

with me able to access it using cURL (and in a browser):-

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
{
 "name" : "irt6ohl",
 "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
 "cluster_uuid" : "jtqcAMyJTRunrxobr6zE_g",
 "version" : {
  "number" : "6.8.1",
  "build_flavor" : "default",
  "build_type" : "docker",
  "build_hash" : "1fad4e1",
  "build_date" : "2019-06-18T13:16:52.517138Z",
  "build_snapshot" : false,
  "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
  "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
  "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
 },
 "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My database is up, migrated and seeded fine. It seems these three lines in `routes/web.php` break the code:-

```
App\Content::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);
App\Content::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);
App\Content::addAllToIndex();
```

These settings *are* fundamental to the `ElasticSearch` setup?

I've googled around for it and other folks are having similar issues but I'm unable to find a definitive solution. Are you able to shine some light on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that each docker is almost like an isolated environment.

So your app (which is running on http://localhost:3024), is trying to connect to localhost:9200 on that same container. and thus it results in the error you're getting.

To fix this, you need to connect both container through a network.

Read this: [Docker Network Connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

Comment: I have my each service (selenium, elasticsearch) running in the same container.  Do I need to connect them? . I am receving 'No alive nodes found in your cluster' error.

Comment: Generally speaking it's better if you seperate your services (1 service per container), that's the entire point of containers.
However, if you run the services on the same container then no you can just connect them without a network, If you're getting this error then make sure your elasticsearch instances are up and running, and that you are connecting with the correct ip/port